# Auto-assign floating ip to instances while creation

Tags: ip, openstack

I **want to auto-assign floating ip's to instances while its creation.** I have a self service underlying network in my openstack liberty version. 
Lots of posts on internet suggest using nova-network where they have a flag : auto_assign_floating_ip= true but its is not possible. I have neutron where my neutron.conf does not have any config flags related to auto assignment of floating ips. I cannot connect instances directly to my public-external network. 
Instances are connected to internal network which is like : 
**public net--- router--- internal net** . 
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto assigning floating IPs to instances is not possible in neutron and there is no configuration for it in `neutron.conf`. It is just a `nova-network` legacy feature.